# Syncfusion mvc grid control filtering on hyperlink column

Tags: syncfusion

I have just been trying out syncfusion controls for mvc and have come across bit of a hurdle. My problem is that when i use a hyperlink in ej grid column using column template feature the filters just don't work for that column. My current UI is designed that way that i need to render a column value as clickable link and i also need to allow filtering on the basis of value in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform actions like filtering, sorting, grouping **Fields** must be enabled to column. Based on the column value above actions will be performed. To perform filtering in template column,define the **Field** property to template column.

Refer the below code example

```
@(Html.EJ().Grid<EmployeeView>("ColumnTemplate")
    .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource)
    .AllowPaging()
    .ToolbarSettings(toolBar => toolBar.ShowToolbar().ToolbarItems(items =>
     {
       items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.ExcelExport);
       items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.WordExport);
       items.AddTool(ToolBarItems.PdfExport);
     }))       
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.HeaderText("First Name").Field(“FirstName”).Template("#columnTemplate").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(80).Add();
        col.Field("EmployeeID").HeaderText("Employee ID").TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("LastName").HeaderText("Last Name").Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("BirthDate").HeaderText("Birth Date").TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Add();
        col.Field("Country").Width(100).HeaderText("Country").Add();
    })
)
```

Please get back to us if you have further queries.

Comment: Cheers bro. Thanks a lot.